# Artboard dimensions for very large print when using effects?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, artboard, raster, dimensions

I'm new to printing illustrations from Illustrator.  I have a project that needs to be printed to a large canvas (about 10ft x 8ft).  I've got a lot of blur and grain effects, and I'd like these to print clearly.

Is it recommended to set the artboard dimensions to the actual print size in this case?  The .ai file is huge, and I'd like to get the file size down for logistical reasons, while getting as much clarity as I can in the printed illustration.

Are there tradeoffs like setting the Document Raster Effects settings DPI to a certain value, and scaling the artboard to a certain fraction of the final dimensions, that would do the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make your artboard at half the size you will have a file 4 times smaller. 150PPI is more than enough for a large-size print.

Imho the maximum PPI you need is 100PPI. That means that you could make your artboard, either at the correct size at 100PPI or at 1/3 the size at 300PPI. That will be a file 9 times smaller.

Keep whatever is in vectors, in vectors.